# Countdown Unix time

Tags: javascript, html

I try this:

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateClock() {
        var ts = Math.round(((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - <?php echo $userInfo['drive_in_town_time']; ?>) * -1);

        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = ts;
    }    
</script>
```

but in span countdown don't appear nothing?

Comment: Where/when do you call the function `updateClock()`?

Comment: Why the stray Unix, what has Unix to do with this question.

Comment: @richard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time - the time in milliseconds since midnight jan 1 1970 (as returned by getTime()) divided by 1000 (ie, converted to seconds) is called unix time...

Answer (score 0):

Either your PHP code is not functioning properly, or you are not actually calling the function.  I'm guessing you aren't calling the function; you have only shown a function declaration in your code.

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd6AP/).

All I have done is replace the value of your PHP code with `1` and add a call to the function.